# Dynamically populate a button value android

Tags: android, button, dynamic, findviewbyid

I have seen lots of example to which one use a if condition or a case statement to programmatically change the conditions of elements...yadda yadda. I need to change the value of a button based on what the user clicks. Below is the code that I currently have.

```
 Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.polarity);
        btnOpenPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.color); 
final Button finalBtnOpenPopup = btnOpenPopup;         

btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){CONTINUES TO OTHER FUNCTIONS }
```

I basically need to know what button was pressed. Then dynamically populate it into findViewById() function. i.e.

```
btnOpenPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DYNAMTICVALUEOFBUTTONUSERHASPRESSED);
```

This way by the time it gets to the final Button part of the code it will have the value to which the user clicked on. Code works if I only want to have one button or a page mile deep in different configuration (not ideal).

All the examples I have seen so far are after the user clicks the button (which is what I want) but they name the buttons name statically like above code shows but very much static.

Hope that all makes sense.

**UPDATE:**

I think I may have confused the situation. Below is the remaining code. Hopefully this will provide context. The btnOpenPopup needs to remain the same as it's used in the call to execute the command for a new window to actually popup. Hopefully this will provide a bit more context for what I'm trying to achieve.

```
 final Button finalBtnOpenPopup = btnOpenPopup;
        btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.meditationpopup, null);

                //set the title of the popup
                TextView titletext = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.chakratitle);
                titletext.setText(activityName);

                if (activityName.equals("Root"))
                {
                    switch (arg0.getId())
                    {
                        case R.id.color:
                            //Rename the string so to get the value from the string xml
                            String stringName = activityName.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","")+"color";
                            TextView desctext = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.popupDesc);
                            desctext.setText(getString(getStringResource(getApplicationContext(),stringName)));
                        break;
                        case R.id.polarity:
                            //Rename the string so to get the value from the string xml
                            String polarityString = activityName.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","")+"polarity";
                            TextView polarityDesc = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.popupDesc);
                            //polarityDesc.setText(activityName);
                            polarityDesc.setText(getString(getStringResource(getApplicationContext(),polarityString)));
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.polarity);
       btnOpenPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.color);
```

should be

```
 Button btnOpenPopupFirst = (Button)findViewById(R.id.polarity);
 Button btnOpenPopupSecond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.color);
```

you should declare different different button for diffrerent findviewbyid

also in my eclipse it is not accepting

```
btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
```

instead it works with

```
btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}
```

and you need to provide more clear view of what you want to perform

new thoughts,try doing this:

```
 btnOpenPopupFirst.setOnClickListener(this);
 btnOpenPopupSecond.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then option will come on both the above code lines

```
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)
```

choose this

```
let MainActivity implement OnClickListener
```

then this option will come

```
The type MainActivity must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)
```

choose

```
add unimplemented method
```

now

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
```

will be created

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.polarity:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "btnOpenPopupFirst(polarity) is pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//other code to be performed regarding this button
        break;
    case R.id.color:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "btnOpenPopupSecond(color) is pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//other code to be performed regarding this button
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

And post your views after implementing this way.

Comment: I agree your correct in the syntax but I need the btnOpenPopup name to remain the same. Mainly because depending on the button pressed will dictate the outcome.

Comment: Hi Ashish, I have reviewed my logic towards this and appreciate your thoughts on this issue I was having. In doing so I re-reviewed what you had suggested and concluded your thoughts are correct. I was trying to avoid duplication of code. I will come back to this issue later. But I ended up using your suggestion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
 int[] id={R.id.button1,R.id.button2};
 Button b=(Button)findViewById(id[i]);
```

Comment: Hey Jai, I see where you are going with that. By putting it into an array...where the [i] is defined do you need to put it into the int i.e. int[i]

Comment: If u want to have first button id as ur button set id[0] or second button set id[1].. u can set any number of button id thr and use it dynamically..

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. int[] id = {R.id.polarity,R.id.color};
        Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(id[i]); is what I have but "i" is undefined. I have tried declaring it but still same issue. Does that look correct to you? If I put a static value of 0 or 1 in the i it works for the 1 value you specify. So close!!!

Comment: Yes depending on your condition which id must be used.. u need to set ranging from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The onClick method in Button.OnClickListener has a View parameter... you can call getId() on that view to get the id of that button that was clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make too much sense to me.  If what you really want is this:

```
btnOpenPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DYNAMTICVALUEOFBUTTONUSERHASPRESSED);
```

All you need to do is set your value in the `onClick(View view)` method of your `OnClickListener`

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    btnOpenPopup = (Button)view;
}
```